# How to prevent the popping up of the IE Download Manager when downloading a pdf c#

Tags: wpf, pdf, internet-explorer-11, download-manager

when a user is opening a pdf-link in IE11... is it possible to prevent the popping up of the download manager with the options "open and save file"?

My goal is: 
- open pdf link
- open file by adobe Viewer
- no popping up of download manager

Is there a way to this programmatically with c#?

Answer (score 0):

So what you do is just process that link? What if the user has deactivated IE or a different Browser? They all COULD have different Methods to handle that links. If you just want to download a pdf, than you can download if without any extern browser. (For example with the [WebClient.DownloadFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ez801hhe%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) Method).

**ADD:**
Then you could open that file with the [Process.Start](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/53ezey2s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) Method. That means, that the file will be opend as when you double click the file in Windows Explorer (meaning the default program for viewing PDF file will be opened if any exists)

Comment: I am developing a wpf-application which just displays via a Webbrowser an intranet-html-page. The application is for internal business use, so IE is the default browser. The application is used for tablets. The intranet-page provides various pdf-documents. To comply with the usability of tablet, I just want the user to use the application (which is on fullscreen-mode without any window-style) to open and view these pdf-files. Unfortunately, the download-manager leads the user to the desktop-view which I want to avoid.